# php array with in array names don't output

Tags: php, arrays

Is this possible to do?
i'm looking to build a grid of values, but I was wondering if this is possible

```
$section_array = array(
    $array_1[$i],
    $array_2[$i],
    $array_3[$i]
);

for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";

    for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
        echo "<td>" . $section_array[$j] . "</td>"; // 3
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

This is basically the idea, I want to print out 1 value of each section (array_1, array_2) etc
then move to the next day, and print out the values of day 2 and so on. is it possible without having to just list every single one in the 2nd for loop?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do but you have `echo = $section_array...`  Take out the equals sign.

Comment: yea sorry, I was typing out as an example from scratch, its not my actual code, thanks

Comment: There is so much wrong with this code I don't see how your example does us any good to help you. For Example $section_array_count doesn't exist, either does $daycount. Could you please update your question and use a real example.

Comment: Please also include _all_ the code.

Comment: updated, those values don't matter

Comment: What do the key/values look like for each $array_1[$i], $array_2[$i], etc....? It seems like you really should be using foreach()

Comment: they are numbers, doubles

Comment: yes but you have only 3 values, why would you need another loop?
`echo "<tr>";`
    `echo "<td>". $section_array[0] ."</td>";`
    `echo "<td>". $section_array[1] ."</td>";`    
    `echo "<td>". $section_array[2] ."</td>";`
`echo "</tr>";`

Comment: because its not 3 values, I said this is just an example, its 20+ values.

Comment: so yes, it should work, you haven't tried it yet?

Comment: I know that's going to work, that's not what i'm asking, please take 5 seconds to read my question instead of just spamming solutions that I already know work.

Comment: "Is this possible to do? i'm looking to build a grid of values"
Yes it is possible to do so, and you can't echo an array, without printing each one of them, if you want to print the whole array. so please ask questions better so we could understand what you want from us

Comment: below the code it says this. This is basically the idea, I want to print out 1 value of each section (array_1, array_2) etc then move to the next day, and print out the values of day 2 and so on. is it possible without having to just list every single one in the 2nd for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$secname_array = array($val1, $val2, $val3);
$daycount = 31;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $daycount; $i++){
        echo"<tr>
                <td>$i</td>";

                foreach ($secname_array as $v)
                {
                    echo "<td>". $v[$j]. "</td>";
                }
                $j++;
        echo"</tr>";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?  Loop through your array of arrays and print 2 values from the sub array.

```
$arr = //insert data here
foreach($arr as $subarr) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $subarr['myval1'] . '</td><td>' . $subarr['myval2'] . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: not really, I'm trying to avoid having to list each one in the 2nd loop

Comment: this isn't what I actually needed, but the for each got me in the right direction. thanks

Comment: @AlbertD You're welcome.  If you update your question with a little more code on how the array(s) are generated, I can update my answer for you.